# Spring MVC load page without controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

With Spring MVC, when I am going to load one page as JSP, HTML etc, I have to write one controller for it.

How can I load one page directly without controller but in rules, just like structs 2.5?

Comment: Please put some effort into your spelling and grammar. As for the question, use a resource handler.

Comment: I am sorry for my typing and my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DispatcherServlet is presumably mapped to "/", @Sotirios Delimanolis is right, and if you are still confusing, try

(1)use resources element

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Using [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler.html) to handle your static rsources. This is usually better than(2) because spring mvc attached some useful features when serving your resources.

(2)use default-servlet-handler

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

Declaring [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.html) for serving static files using the Servlet container's "default" Servlet.